# Using custom React Hooks in typescript class

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

I know this is a generic question and I don't have any code around it or example, but is it possible to use custom React hooks in a typescript class with `.ts` extension? Or Hooks can only be used in `.tsx` extension?

Comment: You can use hooks in `.ts` files. `.tsx` is if you need to use JSX expressions.

Comment: Did you try creating a hook in a `.ts` and did it not work? It's hard to tell what your question is since it seems like it could be easily answered by just trying it.

Comment: Nope, I'm just spitballing. I have custom hooks defined and would want to use them in class(Not class based components). I saw no code samples online so thought of asking it here. @JuanMendes

Comment: @SimmiGeorge Please do some research before asking. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask where the first step is "Search, and research"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have custom hooks defined and would want to use them in class(Not class based components). I saw no code samples online so thought of asking it here.

Hooks are only conceptually valid in the context of a react component, and only technically allowed in function components.

Without an example to go from your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it's not possible to use hooks inside a class component.
However, you can define hooks in `.ts` files. The only problem is using them in class components.

Answer (score 0):

The custom hooks are often used with react components, but you can use them with other hooks (in a `.ts` file). For example:

```
const myCustomHook = () => {
 const customHook2 = myCustomHook2();
}
```

See more: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html